# how to display crawl html crawl data

Tags: javascript, html

I had crawled a website (http://example.com) with html content and save to database:

```
<html>
<script language="javascript" src="login.js"></script>
<body>
<img src="images/test.gif"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, how can i display this content in my localhost webpage (http://localhost/webpage) that my browser must understand

```
<script language="javascript" src="login.js"></script>
```

is

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://example.com/login.js"></script>
```

and

```
<img src="images/test.gif"/>
```

is

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/test.gif"/>
```

Thanks any help.

Answer (score 3):

Put `<base href="http://example.com/" />` on the top of your HTML page:

```
<html>
<base href="http://example.com/" />
<script language="javascript" src="login.js"></script>
<body>
<img src="images/test.gif"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Even better, use the actual URL as the base href in case you've elements like:

```
<a href="?page=1">link</a
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just store it in a variable

```
$link_start = 'http://example.com/';
...
<img src="<?php echo $link_start; ?>images/test.gif"/>
OR
echo "<img src=\"{$link_start}images/test.gif\"/>";
```

Comment: ...which would require the contents being parsed. I'm not sure if OP did that with websites gathered from crawling.